# Gesture recogniser not working when added button view to the Label view as subview

Tags: ios, swift

I Used a stack view to render labels in it and then added the buttons to the respective labels, used a target to handle the event when button is tapped. Here the handler is not called when added as subview to the label

```
Stackview

label1 
      button1

label2 
      button2

label3
      button3
```

**Function to add button to the labelview**

```
 func setButton(count:Int){

    for i in 0..<count{

        buttons[i].tag = i

        buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDelete(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        label[i].addSubview(buttons[i])

    }
```

**Handler**

```
@objc func handleDelete(_ sender:UIButton){

    print(sender.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the labels userInteraction to true.

Another better solution is to add the button outside the label, so both the label and button are in a container view.